# Close many ports at once

Tags: macos, terminal, kill

When I want to kill a process on a given port (let say `8000`) I'm using command:

```
kill -9 `lsof -i :8000`
```

Is there any way to close many ports at once? I have to kill process on ports `8000-9000` and doing this by hand is pretty inefficient.

Comment: Are you familiar with bash scripts?
If you create a script of the above, take the port range as input parameter(s), and manipulate the line you have above slighty, to make use of your input parameter, you're home :)

Comment: @mattias I don't know much, but if you know any tutorial I'm happy to learn!

Comment: Is your command above working btw? What OS X version do u use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first attempt to give you a working script for this.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {8000..9000}
do
   kill -kill `lsof -t -i tcp:$i`
done
```

Put the above in a .sh file, `myportrangekiller.sh`and make it executable, `chmod +x myportrangekiller.sh` and run it with `$ ./myportrangekiller.sh` from your terminal.
This will loop through ports 8000-9000 and kill those processes.

Hard for me to verify if it works, as I am getting the following when running your command in OS X El Capitan,

> kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec
>   ... or kill -l [sigspec]

Btw, I changed your command slightly, from `lost`to `lost`, kind of assumed that you misspelled that binary's name.

Comment: I am thinking you probably don't want to create and run a thousand `lsof` processes, and you might be better off using a range of ports with `lsof -t -i tcp:8000-9000`

Comment: Well then it's just a one-liner and no need for my bad attempt at looping over OP's initial command.
@Ziva, can you verify that above comment works?